# Python 3 replacement of string regex

Tags: python, regex, string, parsing

I am working with a html script converted into a string

How do I replace all the html code in tags with blank using regex?

Answer (score 22):

Using a relatively simple pattern (for which it might be a good idea to expand on),

```
import re
html = re.sub(r'<.+?>', '', html)
```